# Conditional first run handler

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I wonder if someone can help me with a simple script. I am not a good Titanium programmer yet, but I would like to be some day.

I need help with a script to check whether a certain settings file exists in the applicationDataDirectory.

I need a way to trigger this automatically in app.js:

If file with the with the name: "passWord.txt” does not(!) exist in applicationDataDirectory
then open window:

```
var w = Ti.UI.createWindow
```

I can´t find a event to check for this file and then open this window automatically. This will work as a “first run” event when the app is loaded the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var file =Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,"passWord.txt”);
    if ( file.exists() ) {
        // do your work here.
    }
```

For complete details [Titanium.Filesystem.File](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/desktop/latest/Titanium.Filesystem.File-object.html).